# Azure Policy: Deny If Owner Tag Does Not Exist Or Isn't Email Address

Tags: azure, azure-policy

How do I write an Azure policy that only allows resources to be created if both of these conditions are met:

- The resource has an "Owner" tag assigned to it
- The value of the "Owner" tag is a valid email address format

**EDIT:** I'd only do simple email address validation as it is supposed to just remind people in my company to use their email address and not their full name. I'm not trying to validate *all* possible email addresses.

The regex would probably look something like this:

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+
```

Comment: FWIW, "valid email address format" covers a *lot* of ground. For example, look at the regular expression in [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format).

Answer (score 0):

There is built in policies to enforce a tag and its value that you can leverage to customize your own. If you want to add the tag even if it doesnt exisit, you can use the new [Modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#modify) effect. Here is an [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/samples/Tags/add-tag)

```
{"properties": {
  "displayName": "Add a tag to resources",
  "policyType": "BuiltIn",
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "description": "Adds the specified tag and value when any resource missing this tag is created or updated. Existing resources can be remediated by triggering a remediation task. If the tag exists with a different value it will not be changed. Does not modify tags on resource groups.",
  "metadata": {
     "category": "Tags"
  },
  "parameters": {
     "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
           "displayName": "Tag Name",
           "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
        }
     },
     "tagValue": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
           "displayName": "Tag Value",
           "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'production'"
        }
     }
  },
  "policyRule": {
     "if": {
        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
        "exists": "false"
     },
     "then": {
        "effect": "modify",
        "details": {
           "roleDefinitionIds": [
              "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
           ],
           "operations": [
              {
                 "operation": "add",
                 "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                 "value": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
},"id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/4f9dc7db-30c1-420c-b61a-e1d640128d26",
   "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
   "name": "4f9dc7db-30c1-420c-b61a-e1d640128d26"
}
```

Now for the email address, you can try using contains or not contains. Information [here](http://%7B%20%20%20%20%22properties%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22displayName%22:%20%22Add%20a%20tag%20to%20resources%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22policyType%22:%20%22BuiltIn%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mode%22:%20%22Indexed%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22description%22:%20%22Adds%20the%20specified%20tag%20and%20value%20when%20any%20resource%20missing%20this%20tag%20is%20created%20or%20updated.%20Existing%20resources%20can%20be%20remediated%20by%20triggering%20a%20remediation%20task.%20If%20the%20tag%20exists%20with%20a%20different%20value%20it%20will%20not%20be%20changed.%20Does%20not%20modify%20tags%20on%20resource%20groups.%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22metadata%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22:%20%22Tags%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parameters%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tagName%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22String%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22metadata%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22displayName%22:%20%22Tag%20Name%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22description%22:%20%22Name%20of%20the%20tag,%20such%20as%20'environment'%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tagValue%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22String%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22metadata%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22displayName%22:%20%22Tag%20Value%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22description%22:%20%22Value%20of%20the%20tag,%20such%20as%20'production'%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22policyRule%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22if%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22:%20%22[concat('tags[',%20parameters('tagName'),%20']')]%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22exists%22:%20%22false%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22then%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22effect%22:%20%22modify%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22details%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22roleDefinitionIds%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20],%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22operations%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22operation%22:%20%22add%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22:%20%22[concat('tags[',%20parameters('tagName'),%20']')]%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22value%22:%20%22[parameters('tagValue')]%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20]%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%22id%22:%20%22/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/4f9dc7db-30c1-420c-b61a-e1d640128d26%22,%20%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions%22,%20%20%20%20%22name%22:%20%224f9dc7db-30c1-420c-b61a-e1d640128d26%22%20%7D)